What is a VisibleOnScreenNotifier3D Alternative/Workarund Godot 4.2?
so, i just started learning godot , and i was following godot 3d tutorial from Godot docs "Squash the creeps", it was going great until i encountered the warning sign on VisibleOnScreenNotifier3D node , it said "VisibleOnScreenNotifier3D nodes are not supported when using the GL Compatibility yet" and i tried to switch my compatibility but my device(intel hd 5500 , intel i3 5th gen, Hp notebook) does not support any other except the "Compatibility" version if i try any other it says "Your driver does not support vulkan" i updated the drivers but it didnt work.
VisibleOnScreenNotifier3D gl error
so now im thinking maybe i can make my own function that notifies when something is visible or not.
i tried using area3D to do something but it does not emit any signals like "screen_exited" or "screen_entered" like VisibleOnScreenNotifier3D
.............................

Please provide relevant code and your question.

i used this script on the mob node https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_3d_game/04.mob_scene.html#removing-monsters-off-screen
